# threejs Find intersecting point of arc

Tags: three.js

I have a `TrousGeometry`. I need to translate this geometry to point `C`, intersection point of perpendicular line drawn from center point of each end `A` & `B` of the torus.

https://jsfiddle.net/arundhaj/wkLmv4cn/

[image]
[image]

Comment: And what suppose to happen, when arc's angle is 180 degrees? Could you provide more explanatory pictures with different cases with finding and showing of desired points of translation?

Comment: 180 degree won't be allowed. It can be ignored.

Comment: And with 179 degree the desired point will be far away.

Comment: It should be fine.

Comment: Maybe this forum topic will give you some ideas: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/line-with-rounded-corners/1587?u=prisoner849

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the [`BufferGeometry.translate()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.translate) method on `torusGeometry`.

```
const torusGeometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(
    curveRadius, beginRadius, 32, 64, angle
);
torusGeometry.translate(
    -curveRadius - beginRadius,
    -curveRadius - beginRadius,
    0
);
```

See line 69: https://jsfiddle.net/0L587bxe/

If you don't want to take the thickness of the torus into account, just get rid of `-beginRadius` in the translation.

Comment: This solution works only when `angle` is 90 degree. I'm looking for a generic solution which can be applied to any angles

Comment: Oh, you should've specified that in the original question. What would it look like when it's less than 90° and more than 90°?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've updated the question. Actually need to find the intersection point of perpendicular line drawn from center point of each end of the torus.